# Mysql queries using temporary table slowing

Tags: mysql

I have two databases in mysql.
In one i am firing a query periodically using a stored procedure as follows

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE l_AVG_STD_tbl (
        ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        BusStopID1 VARCHAR(30),
        BusStopID2 VARCHAR(30),
        SlotID INT (11),
        AVG_Time FLOAT ,
        STD_Time FLOAT ,
        VR_Time FLOAT
);
INSERT INTO l_AVG_STD_tbl
        (BusStopID1,
        BusStopID2 ,
        SlotID ,
        AVG_Time ,
        STD_Time ,
        VR_Time)

 SELECT BusStopId1 ,BusStopId2 ,SlotId ,AVG(TimeTaken) ,STD(TimeTaken), VARIANCE(TimeTaken)  FROM PastHistory
 GROUP BY BusStopId1 ,BusStopId2 , SlotId ;
```

*Note: table PastHistory contains around 4 million rows with index on BusStopId1 ,BusStopId2 , SlotId, TimeTaken columns.
In the other database i am firing update and select queries on a table like:

```
update PIS_ETA_CURRENT set  ETA='eta',Destination='destinationName',Send_Flag=0,DBTimestamp= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() where StoppageID='BusStopID' and BusRoute='routeNum' and VehicleNo='vehicleNo';

select t1.BusRoute,t1.Destination,t1.ETA,t1.Send_Flag,t1.DBTimestamp,ceil((t1.ETA - time_to_sec(timediff(NOW(), t1.DBTimestamp))/60)) as ExpectedETA 
from PIS_ETA_CURRENT t1
inner join
(
  select BusRoute,Destination,MIN(ETA) as MINETA from PIS_ETA_CURRENT 
  WHERE  
    StoppageID ='U02838'
    and (((ETA - time_to_sec(timediff(NOW(), DBTimestamp))/60) > 0) or Send_Flag = 0) 
    and ETA<=19 and ETA>=1 
    group by BusRoute,Destination
) t2
  on t1.BusRoute = t2.BusRoute
  and t1.Destination = t2.Destination
  and t1.ETA = t2.MINETA
 WHERE
    t1.StoppageID ='U02838' 
   and (((t1.ETA - time_to_sec(timediff(NOW(), t1.DBTimestamp))/60) > 0) or t1.Send_Flag = 0) 
   and t1.ETA<=19 and t1.ETA>=1 
 order by t1.Send_Flag, (t1.ETA - time_to_sec(timediff(NOW(), t1.DBTimestamp))/60) limit 10;
```

*Note: The table PIS_ETA_CURRENT contains around 100 thousand rows with index on StoppageID, BusRoute,VehicleNo

All tables are MyISAM as it is a legacy system. I am running mysql 5.0 with quad core server and 32G ram.

The system works fine but as soon as the first query starts executing the next two queries slow down which are not even in the same database.

On debugging i felt that it is because both the first and third queries create temporary tables. The first one on disk and second one in memory. So i increased tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M from 32M. But still the issue persists.